# Trying to separate questions from an answers in an online form using regex in R

Tags: r

I am reading a form into a data frame in R. One of the columns have the contents of the form including both the Questions and the answers. I am trying to separate the two without going through every question combination for the various forms. The structure of the data looks like this

```
text <- c('Select the benefit your question is related to: Life or AD&D Insurance\r\n What is your question?: I am interested in purchasing additional life insurance and was wondering if someone could assist me with locating my most recent Life Insurance Statement.\r\n')

number <- c(1)

df <- data.frame(number,text)
```

So each question start on a new line and ends with a colon.

So I would like to end up with a list of questions and a list of corresponding Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split the text into the individual lines. Then,  a simple regex allows you to pull out the Questions and Answers.

```
Lines = unlist(strsplit(text, "\r\n"))

Questions = sub("(.*?):.*", "\\1", Lines)
Answers   = sub(".*?:(.*)", "\\1", Lines)

Questions
[1] "Select the benefit your question is related to"
[2] " What is your question?"                       
Answers
[1] " Life or AD&D Insurance"                                                                                                                                     
[2] " I am interested in purchasing additional life insurance and was wondering if someone could assist me with locating my most recent Life Insurance Statement."
```

Comment: Great. This worked. There are two questions with two corresponding answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr::str_match_all` :

```
tmp <- lapply(stringr::str_match_all(df$text, '\\s*(.*?):\\s*(.*?)\r\n'), 
               function(x) x[, -1])
result <- cbind(id = rep(df$number, sapply(tmp, nrow)), 
                do.call(rbind.data.frame, tmp))
names(result) <- c('question', 'answer')
result
```

Comment: This worked great. I have thousands of questions and each group of questions is associated with a unique identifier store in say df$id. How can I add this identifier to the results so I can retrieve all the questions associated with a specific id?

Comment: @user3482393 Check the updated answer.

Comment: Couple of things. This works on most cases, but some fail. If all items have two or more questions, it works. But some of the items only have on question and one answer. So when we try to convert the list into a data frame it fails. Also could you explain the regex statement '\\s*(.*?):\\s*(.*?)\r\n' and also the function of function(x) x[, -1] inside the lapply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use `gsub` and the efficient code would be:

```
df<-data.frame(question=gsub("[?][:].*","?",text), answer=gsub(".*[?:]","",text),id=1)
```

The pattern I wrote would search for the first incident of `?:` as I saw you used this combination to separate the questions from answer. So if there is more than one instance of `?:` then the `gsub` will consider the first one to separate questions from answers. this code replaces anything after `?:`  with a single `?`mark to form the question part of the given text, so if you do not need a question mark at the end of question you can change that part to :
`question=gsub("[?][:].*","",text)`

The output is:

```
df$answer 
[1] I am interested in purchasing additional life insurance and was wondering if someone could assist me with locating my most recent Life Insurance Statement.\r\n
```

and the question:

```
df$question
[1] Select the benefit your question is related to: Life or AD&D Insurance\r\n What is your question?
```

Comment: This almost worked, but the first questions ends in : not ?: so the first answer is squeezed between the two questions. Might be able to modify the pattern to get both questions.